# Need an Oracle Pro*C program that queries for all of a user's tables

Tags: sql, c, oracle

I'm new to Pro-C and Oracle (but not databases) so I probably need some fundamental help on what I'm doing wrong. I wrote the following Pro*C program to query for all the tables owned by a specific user:

```
#include <stdio.h>

EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;

int main() {
  int i;
  char oraCreds[10] = "user/pass";
  char tables[50][50], parts[50][50];
  exec sql connect :oraCreds;
  if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0) {
    printf("ERROR abbreviated\n");
    return(0);
  }

  EXEC SQL SELECT TABLE_NAME
    INTO :tables
    FROM USER_TABLES;

  if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0) {
    printf("ERROR: Could not query database for user tables\n");
    printf("\tError Code: %d\n", sqlca.sqlcode);
    printf("\t%.*s\n", sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrml, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      printf("\nTable %d: %s\n", i+1, tables[i]);
    }
  }

  // Code below inserted here

  return(0);
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not query database for user tables
  Error Code: 1403
  ORA-01403: no data found
```

The problem is that there are records in user_tables and in sqlplus I can do a typical `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;` in order to verify that.

In an attempt to verify some of the basic functionality of above program, I inserted the following query at the comment.

```
EXEC SQL SELECT NAME, PART_NO
  INTO :tables, :parts
  FROM ITEMS;

if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0) {
  printf("ERROR: Could not query database for user tables\n");
  printf("\tError Code: %d\n", sqlca.sqlcode);
  printf("\t%.*s\n", sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrml, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
} else {
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    printf("\nTable %d: %s\n", i+1, tables[i]);
  }
}
```

This second query gives the expected results and prints out one line for each item's name.

If I understand correctly, the table, user_tables, is a standard part of Oracle, so is there something special about it that would be throwing off my query? I've started reading some alternate ways to query for the user's tables, but I would love to know why the above method does not work.

Comment: Are the Pro\*C and SQL\*Plus sessions connected as the same user?

Comment: yes, they are, but good thought since I forgot to mention that